# terraform remote state files returns the vpc-id value with double quotes

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using terraform ver > 4.0.
AWS terraform script *vpc_id = data.terraform_remote_state.networking.outputs.vpc_id* throws an error Invalid VPC ID 'vpc-0006e011c1xxxxxxxx' does not exist.

```
module "security_group" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
  version = "~> 4.0"

  name        = local.name
  description = "xyz - mssql security group"
  vpc_id      = data.terraform_remote_state.networking.outputs.vpc_id

  # ingress
  ingress_with_cidr_blocks = [
  {
  from_port   = 1433
  to_port     = 1433
  protocol    = "tcp"
  description = "SqlServer access from within VPC"
  cidr_blocks = data.terraform_remote_state.networking.outputs.vpc_cidr
},
]

tags = local.tags
}
```

This is due to the fact that data.terraform_remote_state.networking.outputs.vpc_id expression returns the value in double-quotes. - Could you pls suggest how to fetch this value without quotes?
Code snippet:

I greatly appreciate your help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual TF code producing the error?

Comment: @Marcin   module "security_group" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
  version = "~> 4.0"

  name        = local.name
  description = "Test security group"
  vpc_id      = data.terraform_remote_state.networking.outputs.vpc_id

  # ingress
  ingress_with_cidr_blocks = [
    {
      from_port   = 1433
      to_port     = 1433
      protocol    = "tcp"
      description = "SqlServer access from within VPC"
      cidr_blocks = data.terraform_remote_state.networking.outputs.vpc_cidr
    },
  ]

  tags = local.tags
}

Comment: The issue is similar to this https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/invalidvpcid-notfound-while-vpc-is-created/5797 - Not sure how to fix this when value fetched from remote state file with quotes for TF ver > 4.0.

Comment: Please update the question with correctly formatted new code.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I've added the code on the initial post now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can pass the value to **trim** function ?

This function removes the specified set of characters from the start and end of the given string.

```
 vpc_id = trim(data.terraform_remote_state.networking.outputs.vpc_id, "\"")
```

Or

```
vpc_id = trim(data.terraform_remote_state.networking.outputs.vpc_id, "\'")
```

Comment: @Thanks Tolis, I tried both trim functions, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Its turned to be version incompatibility after updating below code it works fine without any error.

```
terraform {
required_version = ">= 0.13.1"

required_providers {
aws = {
  source  = "hashicorp/aws"
  version = ">= 4.0"
}

random = {
  source  = "hashicorp/random"
  version = ">= 3.1"
}
```

}
}

**Before Fix:**

```
terraform {
required_version = ">= 0.13.1"

 required_providers {
aws = {
  source  = "hashicorp/aws"
  version = ">= 4.0"
  }
    }
   }
```